# Is there a language where semantic aspect determines which tense is unmarked in a verb?

Tags: morphology, verbs, tense, aspect, conjugation

For every language there is a tense that is morphologically closest to the root, e.g. English present is more basic than perfect since perfect either adds a suffix *-(e)d* or has ablaut as tense marker. Is there a language where some verbs (simplistically "verbs with perfective semantics [VPS]") such as *find*, *come*, *say* are unmarked in preterite, the perfective tense, and marked in present, the imperfective tense; whereas other verbs, those "with imperfective semantic tense" (VIS) such as *search (for)*, *walk*, *talk (about)* are marked in the preterite and unmarked in present?
E. g.

*nenden* ("walk") > pres. *nen*, pret. *nend**ud*** ("walked").

*niden* ("vanish, go away") > pres. *nid**un***, pret. *nid*

(I suppose English has monosyllabic preterite forms for VPS such as *put*, *cut* for phonological reasons (unchanging ablaut of verbs with stem vowel *u*) not because the verbs are VPS. Ancient Greek had a very basic past tense in the aorist, arguably more basic with the VPS twin of verb roots such as *peithō*, cf. *epithon* (perfective: "persuade") vs. *epeisa* ("woo").)

Comment: What language are nenden and niden?

Comment: I think “put” and “cut” are weak verbs with irregular coalescence of the dental suffix with the stem-final dental consonant

Comment: @sumelic yes, probably.

Comment: @fdb those are fictional examples

Comment: There are 22 verbs in the Zero-suffix monosyllabic dental-final class: _bet  
bid  
burst  
cast  
cost  
cut
fit  
hit  
hurt  
let  
put
quit
rid
set
shed
shit
shut
slit
spit
split
spread
thrust_.

Comment: @jlawler. What if these zero-suffix monosyllabic dental-final class verbs are onomatopoetic as to their perfectivity because (i) they end in a stop (final dental stop) thus denoting finality or transition of state and (ii) have coalescence of the dental suffix (_-ed_) and the dental stem rime as opposed to VIS which do not have contracted preterites because they cannot coalesce the perfective suffix dental stop with the rime stop: _ran_ (*_runned_), _rushed_, etc. Then _put_ and _cut_ would not simply be phonologically contracted.

Comment: But they have nothing in common semantically, and they don't deal with sound, so it's strange to call them  onomatopoetic.

Comment: Onomatopoetic is an exaggeration, admittedly the whole power of language stems from the fact that the signifier does not emulate the structure of the signified. Nevertheless I consider onomatopoiesis to be one end of a spectrum of synaesthesia. Perfectivity is abstract but I believe that there is a crosslinguistic tendency for VPS to have more stops in their stem('s coda) than VIS, and probably semelfactives stops as initials AND codas, e.g. a verb for hitting would sound less fitting if its stem consisted of continuants only. I know this is a far reach, easily overridable, but cf. kiki/bouba.

Answer (score 1):

This is true for many old Indo-European languages because the present stem was often extended with infixed *-e-* (see the answer from @fdb with Greek p**e**ith-o, e-pith-o-n, pe-p**o**ith-a), but sometimes even with infix *-n-*, e.g. Latin *li**n**qu-o* ("I leave") with the past *liqu-i* ("I left") or Vedic present *yu**na**j-m-i* ("I join") vs past *a-yuj-a-t* ("He joined").

Answer (score 0):

To stick with your Greek example: present πείθω, strong aorist ἔπῐθον, perfect πέποιθα reflect the stems peith, pith, poith. I do not see that any of these is unmarked or that any other of them is marked. This is regular ablaut gradation with e, o, and zero grades.

Comment: This opposes prototype theory and the theory of language acquisition and entrechment. We learn verbs by becoming acquainted with its most salient forms first and foremost. _peith_, _pith_ and _poith_ are not equal in respect of "basicness" nor saliency. One of these three stems must have been learned first and used more often than the other ones. Thus either _peith_ and _poith_ are extensions of _pith_ or _pith_ is a derivation/inflection of either _peith_ or _poith_ by reduction. Or otherwise _peith_ produced _poith_ and _pith_, being basic tense stem.

Comment: Your question was about "marked" and "unmarked", not about language acquisition.

Comment: Ablaut gradation is a form of marking.

Comment: So what is the unmarked form in the paradigm of πείθω?

Comment: Hard to say. Eleshar has offered an answer. Here is a paper that offers models of unidirectionality for ablaut gradation: [link](https://www.yumpu.com/en/document/view/29300721/modern-german-and-old-english-strong-verbs-two-ways-of-running-). If you were to ask which stem is closest to the root I would say _pith_, if you were to ask which stem comes first in Ancient Greek ablaut I do not know. Certainly _peith_ precedes _poith_. I find it hard to believe that ablaut grades are equally primary considering that to be able to tell which grade refers to which tense one needs to know where to start